# Running ruby script with eventmanager on startup

Tags: boot, cron, ruby

I hope somebody can help me with the following.

I need my Raspberry to run a ruby script on startup which uses ruby's eventmachine package. I've installed rvm, the correct ruby version (2.1.0-dev), and all necessary packages.

If I start the script manually (using a `startup.sh` that calls the ruby script), all runs well.

However, when the script is called from `crontab` (using `@reboot`), it gives the error message (in an output file) that `it cannot load the eventmachine file`.

If I then log on to raspberry and run the script again (without doing anything else in between), everything works fine. It seems as if the script starts before **rvm** is properly set up, but this doesn't happen only at shell login, does it?

I'm calling ruby with an absolute path `/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-dev/bin/ruby`, so that also can't be it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to run the script from rc.local? It is useful and easier than cron for only running scripts at startup.

Documentation:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

Short example (but for Python): https://youtu.be/3_HGUlcA4gQ